# Appropriate to use main method as just the kickoff?

Tags: java, coding-style, program-entry-point

**I'm wondering:** What's the best use of the main method in a shorter (but with potential of getting longer) program?

**Here's what I mean:** When I start a project. I generally start out with a `MainController`. I use this to control the flow of my program. In the past (and currently) I have been doing something like this:

```
public class MainController {

//Note, normally I'll do some singleton patter stuff here, but I believe that's irrelevant to this question

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainController mc = new MainController();
    mc.begin();
  }

  public void begin() {
    //my code here
  }
}
```

**I would like opinions about**: Is it better to just have your main code in your main method like the following code, or to do it as I have been doing it (like in the previous code)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //my code here
}
```

Note: I realize this may be a bit of an opinion based answer, but I'm curious to see where the votes go. Thanks.

Comment: Why write more code without clear purpose?

Comment: @NikolaKolev, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use the approach you have mentioned first,ie,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainController mc = new MainController();
    mc.begin();
  }

  public void begin() {
    //my code here
  }
```

Reason being, that the `begin()` method is supposed to do the stuff that `begin()` should do. And as we target for [**high cohesion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29), this should be the approach. Each method doing what it should do. `main()` is just a point to start off your program, that doesn't mean it should do all the stuff that you can think for that particular class.

Answer (score 1):

At least for readabilities sake, I always start off with your 1st approach. In the sense that I could choose to name my custom method whatever I want. As opposed to putting it all in the main method, which doesn't really describe what I want to accomplish.

That being said, let me offer a counter for the sake of balance: your 1st approach would require the creation of an object and calling a method an this object, which is an overhead. But really, this should not matter.